# Plone app named "MyApp" crashes Plone

Tags: crash, plone

I used the "paster" command that comes in the "bin/" directory of my Plone's instance folder to create a plone app (from template) named "MyApp" - the command was:

```
(from instance's root folder):> ./bin/paster create -t plone_app
```

When asked for a name, I gave it "MyApp".  I copied this to the "src/" folder and registered it within the "buildout.cfg" file and ran buildout.  I have this process working for other apps with different names, however it seems that THIS particular app always crashes Plone.  When I visit my site, all I get is Zope (and can't access Plone).  Is there a reason why?  Is "MyApp" a reserved namespace for something else that's causing a crash?

I should also note that a name "myapp" works just fine...

Comment: *How* does it crash? If you see Zope, nothing crashed. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting (especially in relation to Maurits' response) that if you use the 'zopeskel' script instead of paster, like so:

```
bin/zopeskel plone_app MyApp
```

You will get an error message telling you that you need a name with two dots.  That's one of the primary reasons to use the 'zopeskel' script instead of the paster command.  When you install zopeskel, you should have a bin/zopeskel right next to bin/paster.  Use it, and you'll get better error messages and inline help.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
aclark@Alex-Clarks-MacBook-Pro:~/Developer/test-4.1/src/ > paster create -t plone_app MyApp
Selected and implied templates:
  ZopeSkel#nested_namespace  A basic Python project with a nested namespace (2 dots in name)
  ZopeSkel#plone_app         A project for Plone products with a nested namespace (2 dots in name)

Variables:
  egg:      MyApp
  package:  myapp
  project:  MyApp
Expert Mode? (What question mode would you like? (easy/expert/all)?) ['easy']: 
Version (Version number for project) ['1.0']: 
Description (One-line description of the project) ['']: 
Creating template nested_namespace
Creating directory ./MyApp
  Recursing into +namespace_package+
    Creating ./MyApp/MyApp/
    Recursing into +namespace_package2+
      Creating ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/
      Recursing into +package+
        Creating ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/
        Copying __init__.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/__init__.py
      Copying __init__.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/__init__.py
    Copying __init__.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/__init__.py
  Copying README.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/README.txt
  Recursing into docs
    Creating ./MyApp/docs/
    Copying HISTORY.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/docs/HISTORY.txt
  Copying setup.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/setup.py
Creating template plone_app
  Recursing into +namespace_package+
    Recursing into +namespace_package2+
      Recursing into +package+
Replace 0 bytes with 86 bytes (0/0 lines changed; 3 lines added)
        Copying __init__.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/__init__.py
        Copying configure.zcml_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/configure.zcml
        Copying tests.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/tests.py
        Copying version.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/MyApp/plone/MyApp/version.txt
  Recursing into docs
    Copying INSTALL.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/docs/INSTALL.txt
    Copying LICENSE.GPL to ./MyApp/docs/LICENSE.GPL
    Copying LICENSE.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/docs/LICENSE.txt
Replace 890 bytes with 973 bytes (0/32 lines changed; 4 lines added)
  Copying setup.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/setup.py
```

With buildout:

```
aclark@Alex-Clarks-MacBook-Pro:~/Developer/test-4.1/ > cat buildout.cfg 
[buildout]
extends = http://dist.aclark.net/build/plone/4.1.x/develop.cfg
develop = src/MyApp

[plone]
eggs += 
    MyApp
```

Obviously this is not the result you expect though, paster created a triple nested namespace package called "MyApp.plone.MyApp" :-)

Further note: this app will not appear in Add-ons in Plone, unless you add a GenericSetup profile in MyApp/plone/MyApp/configure.zcml like so:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="MyApp.plone.MyApp">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="MyApp"
      directory="profiles/default"
      description="MyApp"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
  />

</configure>
```

Then you should see:

[image]

Finally, there is nothing "wrong" with non-namespace packages, they are just convention (with pros/cons over flat namespace packages, and vice versa). See:

- https://github.com/collective/loo

for an example of a "flat" namespace Plone package.

Answer (score 2):

When I try that command it starts up like this:

```
$ paster create -t plone_app
Selected and implied templates:
  ZopeSkel#nested_namespace  A basic Python project with a nested namespace (2 dots in name)
  ZopeSkel#plone_app         A project for Plone products with a nested namespace (2 dots in name)
```

This means that instead of MyApp you should choose a name with two dots, like plone.app.mine.  When you just give MyApp as project name it apparently creates a package MyApp.plone.MyApp.

Yes, it would be nicer if paster (zopeskel) would give an error here.

Actually, when I fill in MyApp here and use that in a Plone 4 site it does actually start up.  So it may help to paste the exact traceback you get.  But best is probably to pick a better name.

Plone itself uses nested namespaces for some packages (like plone.app.locales).  For your own projects I would say it is overkill.  Instead try it with 'paster create -t plone' which expects a name like my.app or clientname.theme.